# Why FileManager.default.attributesOfItem returning current date in NSFileCreationDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

Though I have checked other answers about how to get the creation date, but that don't seem working out for me.

This is how I am extracting the creation date.

```
class func extractFileCreatedDate(filepath: String) -> String{

    var dateString = ""
    do{

        let aFileAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filepath) as [FileAttributeKey:Any]
        let theCreationDate = aFileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] as? Date ?? Date()

        let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale?
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "GMT")
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

        //MARK:- Share App Submit Date
        if let readDate:String = formatter.string(from: theCreationDate){
            dateString = readDate
        }

    } catch let theError as Error{
        print("file not found \(theError)")
    }

    return dateString
}
```

**So the response I Got by printing is:**

[image]

**And if I check this file in local storage creation date is different:**

[image]

In debug also I am getting the current date not the creation date:

[image]
[image]

Please suggest me if I am doing something wrong. what I am expecting is it should return the same creation date. Or maybe I am missing something, help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: I ran your code and it returned the correct creation date in my test. – Is only the debugger output wrong, or the returned value as well? And (sorry for asking the obvious) did you triple-check that it is the correct file?

Comment: Yes, I am always getting the wrong date. It should work, don't know what is wrong. I have only one local file and checked it again and again. Even I was also sure, it will return the correct creation date. But it didn't. Please refer screenshot, edited question.

Comment: @RenukaPandey why are you changing Locale and TimeZone, Is there any reason?Try to use only format

Comment: @guru: Using locale is part of the requirements, but before applying format and locale, the creation date is still the current date, you may refer to the screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

**The creationDate will always return the created date of the file from our Application** not the creation date of the physical storage(Mac).

**For test this:**

1: Add a file to your bundle(which is created in past date) and test your code, it will return you the current date(Same as you are getting now).

2: Delete the App change the iPhone’s date manually to any date from past For Ex.**01-01-2019** and run the App, you can see the creation date is **01-01-2019**.

3: Change the date to Today’s date again and test, you can see the result is still **01-01-2019**, because the **creation date is date from past**.

Hope it help you!!!